# Universal Print via GraphApi

Tags: printing, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to print a document to a shared universal printer via the graph api using application authentication (ie. no user interaction) using either client secret or client certificates? I can't seem to find any documentation on this use case.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean that you wanna gather some information via graph api then you need your app to connect to the printer in your office and print the information?

Comment: No, I want to print a document to a printer in my office via graph api. I have an api running in Azure and a client app that calls that api to request a document to be printed. The api needs to print that document to a printer shared on universal print; I am trying to figure out if I can do that by calling graph api.

Comment: Maybe ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/print?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1):

No, currently Application permission type is not supported for creating a print job thru Graph API, you need a delegated user permission for submitting print jobs. Application permission is used in creating print task definition for setup pull printing. More details here: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/universal-print-concept-overview#extending-universal-print-to-support-pull-printing)